# Having error when convert string (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm TT) in SQL DateTime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to convert datetime string (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm TT) to SQL datetime but facing below error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My input in SQL Server:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-06 1:00 PM')
```

Comment: It showing me error in our put window. "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Are you sure you are running that exact code? If so, what version of sql server because there is nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: Yes. I'm facing this issue from last 2 days. My SQL version "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128.0"

Comment: I don't think it is the cause of your error, but worth noting that the format `yyyy-MM-dd` is culture sensitive for `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` in SQL Server. You should either use the format `yyyyMMdd`, or explicitly set your dateformat first `SET DATEFORMAT DMY`. At present your date `2015-08-06` could be interpretted as 8th June, or 6th August depending on settings.

Comment: Are you running that EXACT code, or are you using a column name where that hard coded string value is in your post?

Comment: Does this work for you ? SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-06  1:00 PM', 101)

Comment: @GarethD I tried `yyyyMMdd` but still error throwing. Current date format is `yyyy-MM-dd`. Where I change date format? In my desktop OR in SQL Server?

Comment: @SeanLange Currently I write hard coded but it is dynamic value coming from XML string. I had merge `Date + Time` 2 variables from XML file and then need to convert final string into DateTime and save in one table.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Won't work anymore.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? You only provided the version of SSMS. select @@version

Comment: @SeanLange Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
 Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: Hi Guys, I have restarted my SQL Server and above statement works now. But I have used this same thing in store procedure inside cursor and throwing same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use standard format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD-THH:MM:SS. e.g. 
20150806, or  2015-08-06T01:00:00. It works with any settings.